# Localhost:3000 giving 302 error in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am a newbie and was trying to create and run an application based on nodejs..

While running server.js via nodemon I am getting the following error in the console..

```
Express server listening on port 3000
Mongoose default connection open to mongodb://localhost:27017/foo
GET / 302 18.313 ms - 62
GET / 302 3.115 ms - 62
GET / 302 1.537 ms - 62
GET / 302 1.480 ms - 62
GET / 302 2.280 ms - 62
GET / 302 0.830 ms - 62
GET / 302 0.835 ms - 62
GET / 302 0.895 ms - 62
```

The below is my server.js

```
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var http = require('http');
//var http = require('follow-redirects').http;

var User = require('./models/User');
var Item = require('./models/Item');
var Menu = require('./models/Menu');
var authController = require('./controllers/auth');
var userController = require('./controllers/user');
var menuController = require('./controllers/menu');
var itemController = require('./controllers/item');
var addressController = require('./controllers/address');
var transactionController = require('./controllers/transaction');
var orderController = require('./controllers/order');
var subscriptionMenuController = require('./controllers/subscription');
var config = require('./config');
var async = require('async');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URI);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error: Could not connect to MongoDB. Did you forget to run `mongod`?'.red);
});
// CONNECTION EVENTS
// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + config.MONGO_URI);
}); 

// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
}); 

// When the connection is disconnected
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected'); 
});

// If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection 
process.on('SIGINT', function() {  
  mongoose.connection.close(function () { 
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination'); 
    process.exit(0); 
  }); 
}); 

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
// Force HTTPS on Heroku
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var protocol = req.get('x-forwarded-proto');
    protocol == 'https' ? next() : res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  });
}
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist')));

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Log in with Email
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/login', authController.postLogin);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Create Email and Password Account
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/signup', authController.postSignup, userController.createUser);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Create Email and Password Account
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/email', authController.isUserRegistered);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Login with Facebook
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/facebook', authController.postFacebookLogin);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Unlink Provider
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/unlink', authController.ensureAuthenticated, authController.postUnlink);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/me
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/me', authController.ensureAuthenticated, userController.getCurrentUser);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | PUT /api/me
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.put('/api/me', authController.ensureAuthenticated, userController.updateCurrentUser);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/menus
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/menus', menuController.getMenus);
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/menus
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/api/menus', menuController.postCreateMenu);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | POST /api/items
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/api/items', authController.ensureAuthenticated, itemController.postCreateItem);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/items
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/items', authController.ensureAuthenticated, itemController.getItems)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/items/:id
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/items/:id', authController.ensureAuthenticated, itemController.getItemById)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | PUT /api/items
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.put('/api/items', authController.ensureAuthenticated, itemController.putItems)
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | POST /api/addresses
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/api/addresses', authController.ensureAuthenticated, addressController.postCreateAddress);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/addresses
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/addresses', authController.ensureAuthenticated, addressController.getAddresses)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/addresses/:id
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/addresses/:id', authController.ensureAuthenticated, addressController.getAddressById)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | PUT /api/addresses
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.put('/api/addresses', authController.ensureAuthenticated, addressController.putAddresses)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | POST /api/orders
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/api/orders', authController.ensureAuthenticated, orderController.postCreateOrder)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/orders/:id
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/orders/:id', orderController.getOrderById)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/allorders
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/allorders', orderController.getAllOrders)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/orders
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/orders',  authController.ensureAuthenticated, orderController.getOrders)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | PUT /api/orders/:id
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.put('/api/orders',  authController.ensureAuthenticated, orderController.putOrders)

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | POST /api/payumoney
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/api/pay', authController.ensureAuthenticated, transactionController.postPay);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | POST /payment/:id/success
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/payment/:id/success', transactionController.paymentSuccess)
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | POST /payment/:id/failed
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/payment/:id/failed', transactionController.paymentFailed)


/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | POST /api/subscriptions
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/api/subscriptions', subscriptionMenuController.postCreateSubscriptionMenu) 

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/subscriptions
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

app.get('/api/subscriptions', subscriptionMenuController.getSubscriptionMenus) 

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | GET /api/subscriptions/:id
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/api/subscriptions/:id', subscriptionMenuController.getSubscriptionMenuById) 

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | PUT /api/menus
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.put('/api/subscriptions', subscriptionMenuController.putSubscriptionMenus)
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Start the Server
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

The below is my config.js file:-

```
module.exports = {
  // App Settings
  MONGO_URI: process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/foo',
  TOKEN_SECRET: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || 'YOUR_UNIQUE_JWT_TOKEN_SECRET'
}
```

Comment: it seems like that you din't configure any api entry... at all. there is no routing or something that assist the server to give you any other response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

302 is not an error, it's a redirect. Which you're doing here

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});
```

which results in an endless loop, unless you handle the `/` route somewhere.